# Is there a name for this property of sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, terminology

Suppose we have a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subseteq X$ with $(X,d)$ a metric space, and we have the following property:

> $$\exists x\in X\forall\epsilon>0[|B_\epsilon(x)\cap (x_n)_{n=1}^\infty|=\aleph_0]$$

(That is to say, there exists a point such that for any $\epsilon>0$ there are a (countably) infinite number of terms of the sequence within $\epsilon$ of that point)

### What is the name of this property?

I would rather not invent a name if one exists. I need a name as it is something memorable to remember (and thus link to).

**My idea:**
I quite like "$(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ *hovers around* $x$" and such an $x$ a "*hovering point*". A sequence with this property is a "*hovering* sequence"

Or "*lingers*" so "let $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a *lingering* sequence"

**Equivalent to:**
This property is equivalent to "having a convergent subsequence", but I don't like "let $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence with possibly many convergent subsequences converging to distinct points" or something.

In the terminology of subsequences, what would the set of lingering/hovering points be called? (this is why I gave a name to the property)

Comment: Do you mean https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point

Comment: @math635 $\text{no.}$ There are loads of hovering sequences without limits. Also $(X,d)$ is complete (implied as otherwise $B_\epsilon(x)$ makes no sense, as $x\notin X$ thus $d$ is undefined for $x$) here so contains all of its limit points. Limit points are a property of sets in a topological space, not sequences.

Comment: A limit and a limit point are not the same thing

Comment: $\text{Right}$ @math635

Comment: Considering your sequence as a set and your metric space as a topological space then your definiton of a hovering point and a limit point exactliy coincide. If you read further on the wikipedia page you see that you can also call such points accumulation poi ts or cluster points.

Comment: @math635 yes that's right. I'm not sure what your point is though.  You want me to call such sequences "limit sequences" or what? Not every sequence will have limit points. I'm not sure if you're confirming your understanding or what but I'll try to be helpful: You've identified a condition for a sequence to have a convergent subsequence. If considered as a set it has a limit point. Nothing else. I'm looking for something like "Hey can we come up with a name for.... " okay let me think of an example....

Comment: @math635 take the following: "Every open cover has a finite subcover" is equivalent to (in a metric space) "every sequence contains a convergent subsequence" and also if the space is totally bounded and complete (these come to mind, there are probably more) - this property is _named_ "compactness", similarly I have found some properties (yellow block in question, has a convergent subsequence) and you've found a sufficient condition for it too, I want to know the name of that property, not other things it is implied by, implies, or is equivalent to. But what you've said is right, thanks for try

Comment: The name is "*a sequence with limit points*". You can invent a new one if you prefer, but it likely will not get spread as saying "sequence with limit points" is easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, your description of a *"hovering point"* precisely coincides with the definition of a [limit point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point). Therefore, such sequences (that you have named a *"hovering sequence"*) are best described simply as *"sequences with limit points"*. Your name is shorter, however, as noted by Paul Sinclair, it seems unlikely to catch on given the relatively simple existing description for such sequences.